# angular2 zone event getting triggered after js events

Tags: angular

I have integrated angular2 into existing project that primarily uses JS/Jquery. Existing JS code binds events such as "mousemove", "mousedown", etc. such that every time user clicks or moves anywhere in the page an event is triggered & timer is reset as well as callback function is called (psuedo code below)

```
body.bind("mousemove keydown mousewheel mousedown", function () {           
            if (timer) { 
                clearTimeout(timer); //reset timer function
            }

            // Set a new timer.
            timer = setTimeout(some_callback_function, 5000)
        })
```

Issue is every time any event is triggered below angular2 zone function is also triggered  (For full code refer url => https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4). Is there any way to skip angular2 zone function & events problematically? In other words is there any way we can invoke angular2 zone function manually as & when required.

```
function ZoneTask(type, zone, source, callback, options, scheduleFn, cancelFn) {
            this.runCount = 0;
            this.type = type;
            this.zone = zone;
            this.source = source;
            this.data = options;
            this.scheduleFn = scheduleFn;
            this.cancelFn = cancelFn;
            this.callback = callback;
            var self = this;
            this.invoke = function () {
                _numberOfNestedTaskFrames++;
                try {
                    return zone.runTask(self, this, arguments);
                }
                finally {
                    if (_numberOfNestedTaskFrames == 1) {
                        drainMicroTaskQueue();
                    }
                    _numberOfNestedTaskFrames--;
                }
            };
        }
```

PS:- From stack trace I can see binding is done in 'patchTimer' function in same 'zone.js' file that executes line `var task = zone.scheduleMacroTask(setName, args[0], options, scheduleTask, clearTask);` and calls `function ZoneTask`